# basic authentication error 500

Tags: apache, basic-authentication

I have this .htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /.htpasswds/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

And a .htpassword

```
test:$apr1$zXAu7nnl$612DeubGZ9jDrDPB1S8VO0
```

the directory structure is:

```
/.htpasswds/.htpasswd
/public_html/.htaccess
```

any attempt to login give me a 500 error. In cpanel the error is not registered in error log.

Comment: Then you're looking in the wrong log or something is misconfigured. A 500 error *must* create a log entry somewhere. (The error is most likely the leading `/` in your paths, though. Your htpasswd file is not really in the system's root directory, is it?)

Comment: a 404 error is registered, but not this 500 error.

Comment: Strange. Are you sure you are looking in the error log? And not the access log?

Comment: @Pekka웃, maybe this screenshot can be helpful http://postimg.org/image/t6l77852b/

Comment: Ah, so you're indeed in a directory of that name with it. Not sure what's going on then, maybe un-hide the directory by naming it `htpasswds` - and look out for that error log. Apache 2 has per-site error logs

Answer (score 1):

I've had a very similar problem with cPanel - and error 500 "internal error" upon entering the basic authentication credentials.

The problem seems to stem from cPanel putting the password file into a directory that the apache process could not access. Moving it to the root folder for the account (where the public_html directory is created) fixes the problem for me. The AuthUserFile entry in .htaccess must still point to the absolute pathname for the file, for example:

`AuthUserFile "/home/myaccount/.passwd"`

with the site root being in `/home/myaccount/public_html/`

Comment: Note: you may need to put the password file into the public_html directory as a hidden .passwd file. This may be the case depending on what directory security you have on your account, e.g. "basedir security" enabled that prevents the apache process from accessing anything outside the public_html directory, with the usual exception of /tmp.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is the problem, but my host provider suggests this:

In cpanel 
    Section security
    Option Web Protect

That will generate:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected"
AuthUserFile "/home/abvnfj/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

if apache can not access .htpasswd, it generate Error 500.

in AuthUserFile write full path to .htpasswd file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct absolute path in .htpaswd.

Example: for my bluehost I need

```
AuthUserFile /home7/<username>/public_html/...
```

While the FTP just gave me

```
/wwww/...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same error and I tested `htpasswd` with adding `-p` parameter which generates passwordfile as plaintext. The error was disappeared, but now I don't have any idea why default md5 passwords are causing this error.